# The correct place to put the test of a signup page - Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I need to write a test to check if the title of Signup page is correct. I'm stuck between two places that I can places the test:

Inside users_controller_test.rb using:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "should get new" do
        get :new
        assert_select "title", "Signup"
    end
end
```

Inside site_layout_test.rb using:

```
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "layout links" do
        get signup_path
        assert_select "title", "Signup"
    end
end
```

Which of this is the correct place to put the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signup link is in the Layout, then put it in `SiteLayoutTest`. If it's only on pages served by `UsersController`, put it in `UsersControllerTest`.